# Issue with undeclared identifiers in Objective-C code

Tags: ios, objective-c, undeclared-identifier

My build keeps failing. It says I have a few undeclared identifiers but I am not sure what to declare and how. Please help. This is Objective-C.

This is my ViewController.m `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [dateLabel resignFirstResponder]; //the textField that you will set the selected date
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init]; //declared uidatepicker component

    pickerViewDate = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select the date!"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate; //set your spesific mode

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]]; //or another LocaleIdentifier instead of en_US
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"]; //desired format

    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; //the function would be fired when user change the date in datePicker

    //now preparing the toolbar which will be displayed at the top of the datePicker
    pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked)]; //barbutton item is "DONE" and doneButtonClicked action will be fired when user clicks the button.
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace]; // set the left of the bar

    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    [pickerViewDate addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [pickerViewDate addSubview:datePicker];
    [pickerViewDate showInView:self.view];
    [pickerViewDate setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)]; //you can change the position
}
}

-(IBAction)dateChanged{
NSDateFormatter *FormatDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[FormatDate setLocale: [[NSLocale alloc]
                        initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[FormatDate setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
dateLabel.text = [FormatDate stringFromDate:[UIDatePicker date]];
}

-(BOOL)closeDatePicker:(id)sender{
[pickerViewDate dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
[dateLabel resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}

-(IBAction)doneButtonClicked{
[self closeDatePicker:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)datePicker:(UITextField *)sender {
}
- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender {
}
@end
```

These are my declarations:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *gob;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pd;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *calculate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nd;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *save;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cd;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *reset;
@property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender;
- (IBAction)datePicker:(UITextField *)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender;
- (IBAction)dateLabel:(UITextField)sender;
- (IBAction)pickerToolbar:(UIToolbar)sender;
```

It gives an error for 'textFieldDidBeginEditing', 'pickerViewDate' and 'dateLabel'.
Please help I have searched other questions so I am not just posting without research.

Comment: Don't embed methods inside another.

Comment: i'm sorry, Im a beginner. what does that mean?

Comment: You put the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method inside the `viewDidLoad` method. You can't do that.

Comment: ok thanks. it removed the error for 'textFieldDidBeginEditing' but then added errors for 'datePicker' and 'pickerToolbar'

Answer (score 0):

You have textFieldDidBeginEditing inside viewDidLoad method. They should be separated.

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [dateLabel resignFirstResponder]; //the textField that you will set the selected date
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init]; //declared uidatepicker component

    pickerViewDate = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select the date!"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate; //set your spesific mode

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]]; //or another LocaleIdentifier instead of en_US
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"]; //desired format

    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; //the function would be fired when user change the date in datePicker

    //now preparing the toolbar which will be displayed at the top of the datePicker
    pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked)]; //barbutton item is "DONE" and doneButtonClicked action will be fired when user clicks the button.
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace]; // set the left of the bar

    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    [pickerViewDate addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [pickerViewDate addSubview:datePicker];
    [pickerViewDate showInView:self.view];
    [pickerViewDate setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)]; //you can change the position
}
```

Comment: ok thanks. it removed the error for 'textFieldDidBeginEditing' but then added errors for 'datePicker' and 'pickerToolbar'

Comment: Could you show the whole error message? Did you even created a class variables named `datePicker` and `pickerToolbar`?

Comment: i added what I declared before my DidLoad method. sorry if my terminologies are confusing, i'm more of an android person, but I'm trying to learn xCode

Comment: look at the original question and see what I added to tell you what i mean